# How were the physical characteristics in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

In Kaliyuga, we human have a defined set of normal physical characteristics like height and weight based on the gender male and female.

Similarly, were there any mention of standard physical characteristics of a human, deity or other characters in the previous yugas? Is there a mention that all the people had same characteristics or are they different? Particularly in Mahabharata, Karna, Arjuna etc. did these characters have normal human heights and weights (like us)?

And also I read in some answers on this site where all the characters are aged below hundred years. Are these years counted in demigod years or normal human years?

Comment: Age, hight differ from yuga to yuga...do u want scriptural references for that or u want comparison bw Mahabharat characters...can u pls edit Ur Q to make it more clear?

Comment: "(apart from the abnormal person)" please remove this line. It is not allowed here to say someone or something is abnormal based on gender. See [Be Nice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Karna, Arjuna etc were much taller than people of KaliYuga. I assume they were around 12/13 ft. So even some tennis players like Isner would have looked dwarf when compared to them.